# Eclipse: no shown variables in debugging Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

**Platform I am using**:

- Fedora 20;
- mariadb-5.5.34-2.fc20.x86_64;
- Eclipse Kepler Service Release from www.eclipse.org

I am implementing example

[See here](http://www.simtay.com/simple-crud-web-application-with-jsf-2-1-primefaces-3-5-maven-and-jpa/)

and I am trying to manage to work the login interface.
Actually I am configuring TomEE to use JAAS auth technology.
Since I am having some troubles, I would like to solve them with the help of Eclipse debugging mode. To do that, I:

- setted breakpoint at line number 79 of LoginController.java;
- started TomEE in debug mode;
- executed login.xhtml in debug mode too;

My problem is that I see nothing in debug mode: no variables, etc.
How is it possible? I have been using debugging mode for a long time, but it is my first time in web development.
[Project archive](https://www.wuala.com/Caterpillar/Documenti/canc/laiLogin/?key=eegdrmUt3bZb)

[Click here for a larger Screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img198/9697/dzbk.png)
[image]

Comment: I am not sure the debugger has stopped at all in that picture.  Could you show us another picture putting the breakpoint at line 81?

Comment: @Jorge_B ONE http://imageshack.com/a/img191/9279/q54j.png

TWO
http://imageshack.com/a/img23/5489/9lp5.png

Comment: If the debugger would have stopped in a breakpoint, you would find that in the "Debug" window one of the daemon threads would have spanned into a call stack trace, just like when you call `.printStackTrace()` on a java exception.  Could you show me an image of that?  By clicking on the top of the call stack, you should see the variables in the "Variables" window

Comment: By the way, there is an easier explanation for all this, now I think of it: have you started your Tomcat in debug mode?  You can check it in the "Servers" window under Java EE perspective

Comment: Yes I started Tomcat in debug mode. I do not know how to do what you asked me in '.printStackTrace()' What about the terminated process you can see in  http://imageshack.com/a/img543/9859/pz6f.png

Comment: No, I just meant that, in case that the server stopped in debug mode, you would see in that window the full call trace in the fashion that method paints it.  I don't know what your problem can be, it must be some detail that flees you.  Maybe the class you have put the breakpoint in has been recompiled since you deployed it and the debugger can't find the exact line number because they have changed?

Comment: I did not change the class I putted the breakpoint in. Can a recorded video be better than screenshots? If yes I can record one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44357/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-caterpillar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage bean has not been istantiated for an unknown reason. I opened a new question to fix it.
[Bean not instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017979/bean-not-istantiated)